# Why am I getting random numbers in my output?

Tags: c++, arrays

Please pardon my code as I am fairly new to programming and C++. I am creating a safearray class that checks if the index is out of bounds. I can't figure out why I am getting a random number in my output. I only seem to get the number when the index is out of bounds.

SafeArray.h

```
#ifndef SafeArray_H
#define SafeArray_H

class SafeArray {
    int upperbound;
    int lowerbound;
    int array[200];
public:
    SafeArray(int, int);
    int &operator[](int);
    void print();
};

#endif
```

SafeArray.cpp

```
#include "SafeArray.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


SafeArray::SafeArray(int l, int u) {
    lowerbound = l;
    upperbound = u;
    for (int i = l; i < u; i++) {
        array[i] = 0;
    }
}

int &SafeArray::operator[](int index)
{

    if (index > upperbound || index < lowerbound)
    {
        cout << "array out of bounds" << endl;
    }
    else {
        return array[index];
    }

}

void SafeArray::print() {
    for (int i = lowerbound; i < upperbound; i++) {
        cout << array[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

tester.cpp

```
#include "SafeArray.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int lowerbound;
    int upperbound;
    cout << "Enter a lower bound: ";
    cin >> lowerbound;
    cout << "Enter an upper bound: ";
    cin >> upperbound;
    SafeArray test = SafeArray(lowerbound, upperbound);
    cout << test[101] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
Enter a lower bound: 0
Enter an upper bound: 100
array out of bounds
255812108
Press any key to continue. .

.

Comment: You gave it an out of bounds index, are you surprised it printed nonsense? What is it supposed to print?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The garbage value is because a function MUST return a value unless it was declared `void`. You left out the `return` so Crom only knows what will be returned for printing or even if the program will survive to print at all. It is [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

May I recommend instead

```
int &SafeArray::operator[](int index)
{

    if (index > upperbound || index < lowerbound)
    {
        throw out_of_range("array out of bounds");
    }
    return array[index];
}
```

[`std::out_of_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) can be found with `#include <stdexcept>`

Caller must either catch the exception and carry on or abort. Eg:

```
try
{
    cout << test[101] << endl;
}
catch(out_of_range & oor)
{
    cout << oor.what() << endl;
}
```

Now you either get a number or an error message, but never both.

Answer (score 2):

```
int &SafeArray::operator[](int index)
{
    int *p;
    p = array;
    if (index > upperbound || index < lowerbound)
    {
        cout << "array out of bounds" << endl;
    }
    else {
        return array[index];
    }

}
```

If `index` is out of bounds, your `[]` operator is not returning anything. This is an undefined behavior. Also, your array users may want to know that something unexpected happened. This is one approach to do that:

```
int &SafeArray::operator[](int index)
{
    int *p;
    p = array;
    if (index > upperbound || index < lowerbound)
    {
        throw std::exception("array out of bounds");
    }
    else {
        return array[index];
    }
} 

//...
try
{
  SafeArray test = SafeArray(lowerbound, upperbound);
  cout << test[101] << endl;
}
catch(std::exception& e)
{ 
   std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```